# MooTools Effect Chaining

Tags: mootools

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
var fx = new Fx.Tween($('element'), {
    duration: 500,
    property: 'opacity',
    transition: Fx.Transitions.Quart.easeOut,
    link: 'chain'
});

fx.start(0, 1)
.chain(function() {
    alert('foo');
})
.start(1, 0)
.chain(function() {
    alert('bar');
});
```

Which then fades in #element, and then runs a function. However, I can't get it to run the second start after the first chain(), which means that #element isn't fading back in.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you could just do something like this http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/FkCgY/ (1.2.x+) are you in 1.12 by chance?

Comment: I'm in 1.3 (the latest from the site as of yesterday). I already have a method similar to that using nesting (that works), but I'd rather avoid that and use a simple chaining mechanism.

Comment: no worries, we got that too :) http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/FkCgY/4/ chain works that way when extending a class: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class.Extras#Chain

Comment: Thanks, that's closer to what I had in mind and have now implemented it. Is there no way to get something similar to the above? It looks like the most elegant to me. I tried implementing Chain into Fx.Tweet with no luck.

Comment: i dont think so. `instance.chain().something()` seems not to work as chain does not return the instance at a glance, i can be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that something very similar to the above code can work except you need to use callChain() in order for the next "link" to fire.. This is what I'm using now:

```
var effect = new Fx.Tween($('element'));
effect.start('opacity', 1)
.chain(function() { /* Do stuff */ this.callChain();)
.chain(function() { /* Do stuff */ this.callChain();)
.chain(function() { /* Do stuff */ this.callChain();)
.chain(function() { /* Do stuff */ this.callChain();)
.chain(function() { /* Do stuff */);
```

And so on.

This is because chain returns and instance of the Chain class, rather than an instance of Fx.Tween. I'm a little annoyed that I need to use callChain() but it's better than having loads of nested functions.